# React Router / Redux - Connected Component Not Passing Redux State to Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am connecting a component to the redux store, but only the react-router props are passed. Not even setting a `testVar` in the `mapStateToProps` function works.

Code simplified:

```
//index.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk' 
import {initialState} from './reducers/RootReducer';

const store = createStore(RootReducer,initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    ), document.getElementById('root'));

// App.js
import Home from './path/to/Home-component'
import About from './path/to/About-component'
...
<div>
<Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
      <Route path='/uploadsideletters' component={About}/>
      ...
    </Switch>
</div>
...

// About.js
...
  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(About);

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    ...state,
      testVar: "test"
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // empty for now
  });
```

When printing `this.props` in the render method to the console I get:
`Object {history: Object, location: Object, params: Object, route: Object, routeParams: Object…}`
My testVar is not there. Why is this?

Comment: Did you imported `connect()`?

Comment: Maybe you import the component, not the container. That's why testVar prop is not passed.

Comment: @Dupocas yes `import { connect } from 'react-redux'`

Comment: @VladBîcu In this case I only have one About component, which is what's above.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was a simple mistake in the end. I've update the question and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As simple minded as it seems, the issue was that I was calling `connect(...)` before  the `mapStateToProps()`and `mapDispatchToProps()`.

Changing the connect portion, now looks like:

```
// About.js
...

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    ...state,
      testVar: "test"
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // empty for now
  });

  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(About);
```

Comment: It should have given error if `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` were declared and defined afterwards.